# gRPC - How many stubs/clients should I use?

Tags: grpc

I am currently developping a massively multi-threaded application that heavily relies on gRPC (only one service)

As I am using a single `Channel` object shared  between threads, the number of stubs/clients I should use is not clear to me.

How many stubs should I instantiate in this case (1 or n)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. `Channel`s are the expensive object, whereas stubs/clients are lighter weight. Each stub/client will be an allocation, but otherwise don't really have much overhead.

In Java, you are free to share stubs as they are thread-safe.